# JavaScript Code Is Not Working In Ajax Model PopUp

Tags: javascript, asp.net

in my webpage in a model PopUp Window i am comparing ages present in two textBox,using javascript but somehow it is not working.
kindly help to overcome from this issue.
Thanks In Advance.
my javascript code is

```
 function CompareAge() {
        var maxage = document.getElementById('<%=txtMaxAge.ClientID%>');
        var minage = document.getElementById('<%=txtMinAge.ClientID%>');
        var val = 'false';
        if (maxage>=minage) {               
            val = 'true';
            return true;
        }
        if (val == 'false') {
            alert('Max-Age Alaways greater than or Equal Min-Age');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and popup window is like this

```
<ul>
 <li>
     <asp:Button ID="btnCancelInPopUpReservation" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Cancel" />
</li>
<li>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSaveInPopUpReservation" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSaveInPopUpReservation_Click" ValidationGroup="g" OnClientClick="if(!CompareAge()) return false;"/>
</li>
```

Comment: What is the error/problem you are facing?

Comment: is the popup html structure already present on the page?

Comment: it is not working,means after save button click it is not validating the value in textbox,if max age <min age yes popup html structure is present in textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried your piece of code I think the problem lies here you should use `.value` for getting value in `var maxage` and `var minage`.

`document.getElementById('<%= txtMaxAge.ClientID %>').value
document.getElementById('<%= txtMinAge.ClientID %>').value`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CompareAge() {
        var maxage = document.getElementById('<%= txtMaxAge.ClientID %>').value;
        var minage = document.getElementById('<%= txtMinAge.ClientID %>').value;
        var val = 'false';
        if (maxage >= minage) {
            val = 'true';
            return true;
        }
        if (val == 'false') {
            alert('Max-Age Alaways greater than or Equal Min-Age');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @akvickyit7 tick would be appreciated :)